# Result of where query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am performing a db search as below:

```
abc = params[:search]      
Model.where("column_name ilike ?", "%#{abc}%")
```

When I am searching nothing it is running like below:

```
Model.where("column_name ilike ?", "%%")
```

which is giving me all rows of table.

When my search param is empty I want it to run like:

```
Model.where("column_name ilike ?", "")
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I noticed you never accept the answers given to your questions. Make sure to go over your questions some time and accept the best answers given they solve your question. This way you let the community know, that the problem is solved and at the same time you reward the effort of the one, who has provided the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just check whether the params is an empty string:

```
Model.where("column_name ilike ?", abc.blank? ? '' : "%#{abc}%")
# or, more strict check
Model.where("column_name ilike ?", abc == '' ? '' : "%#{abc}%")
```

Comment: @MayureshSrivastava No probs, please make sure to accept the answer if that worked for you. Also, see the comment I left under your question.